# How to match 2 date field in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get results if 2 date fields are matching. i have tried below query. Its not returning results if both date field has same value

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [ 
{
"script": {
"script": {
"source": "doc['ExeDate'].value == doc['InputDate'].value",
"lang": "painless"
}
}
},
{
"range": {
"InputDate": {
"gte": "2022-03-01",
"lte": "2022-03-18"
}
}
}
],
"should": []
}
},
"from": 0,
"size": 2,
"sort": []}
```

Mapping in index

```
properties": {
"ExeDate": {
"type": "date"
},
"InputDate": {
"type": "date"
},
```

Also how can we convert date into dd-MM-yyyy format if below value returned as dd-MM-yyyyTHH:MM:SS.000Z. doc['InputDate'].value

Comment: Can you break down your queries and check individually if any is matching? Let us know.

Comment: Getting results if i kept only range criteria,  {
"range": {
"InputDate": {
"gte": "2022-03-01",
"lte": "2022-03-18"
}

Comment: This condition is also working if both dates are in same format. "source": "doc['ExeDate'].value == doc['InputDate'].value",.currently i have one date with dd-MM-YYYY format and other in dd-MM-YYYYTHH:MM:SS.ZZZ. how do i convert this in Elastic search